# Javascript/Jquery Closure Image Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take items from an array and substitute them into an `<img>` tag with a delay so I can see the images changing. It works perfectly in my fiddle, but won't work at all in Chrome on a stand alone html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var x = ['http://static.myce.com/images_posts/2014/12/myce-popcorn-time.png','http://static.myce.com/images_posts/2014/12/myce-popcorn-time.png','http://static.myce.com/images_posts/2014/12/myce-popcorn-time.png']
    function test1(){
}
    var l = 0; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    function test2(){
for (l; l < x.length; l++) {
   $("#img").delay(1000).animate({ opacity: '0' }, (function(l) {
       return function() { $(this).attr("src", x[l]).attr("width", 100); }
   })(l)).delay(1000).animate({ opacity: '1' });

}}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="img" src="http://static.myce.com/images_posts/2014/12/myce-popcorn-time.png"/>
<script>
test2()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. Can you include any additional information that would help lead to a possible cause of this problem? "It doesn't work" isn't very informative.

Comment: Does the console on your stand alone page show any errors?

Comment: My console log says:  Uncaught ReferenceError: test2 is not definedjquerytest.html:24 (anonymous function)

Comment: Ah, OK in your fiddle everything except your call to test2 is wrapped in a window load event I'm guessing. Move your call for `test2()` to the last line inside your document ready call and see if that fixes it. Looks like you're calling `test2()` before it exists.

Comment: Kevin, the <img> tag loads the picture, but the function itself doesn't run. There is no animation or delay of any kind.

Comment: Yep, I thought I could call it later, but even wrapped in its own document.ready it was being called to quickly. I got it now, and thank you so much for your help!